# How do I add a dropdown menu in every row of a column for ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid and I want to add a column in which every row has a dropdown, I see how to add a dropdown to the column just once but not for every row.

Comment: are you on enterprise version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093485/how-to-add-conditional-template-on-ag-grid/39386577#39386577

Answer (score 0):

If you are on enterprise version, you can use the context menu, here is an snippet from an app I'm working on

```
function getContextMenu(params){
    var result;

      switch (params.column.getId()) {
          case 'Title':
              result = [
                  'copy',
                  'toolPanel'
              ];
```

and in **gridOptions**

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: colDefs,
    rowData: null, // I set data later
    getContextMenuItems: getContextMenu
```

So in my context menu function I see where the user clicked, if he clicked on the row *Title* I dispaly only the *copy* and *tool* panel items, and then I can keep adding 'cases' for my switch and set uniqe menu items for each row.