# how to add conditional template on ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

can I do a conditional template on the first column below?

for example:
If my row has score property and I want to hide the input when my score is above 70?

```
let columns = [
            { width: 30, suppressSorting: true, suppressMenu: true, template: '<input type="checkbox">' },
            { headerName: "Score", filter: 'number', valueGetter: (params : any) =>
                params.data.traces ? (<Alert> params.data.traces[0]).severity : params.data.severity, width:70},
            { headerName: "Behaviour tags" },
            { headerName: "Host", field: "host_name" },
            { headerName: "Group Id", cellRenderer: 'group', width:140 },
            { headerName: "Comments",width:290 }
        ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cellRenderer property in your column object

```
let columns = [{ width: 30, suppressSorting: true, suppressMenu: true,
    cellRenderer: function (params) {
        var display = 'block';
        if (params.data.score > 70) {
            display = 'none';
        }

        var html = '<input type="checkbox" style="display: ' + display + '">';

        return html;
    }
}]
```

In params.data you have all row data

Comment: Thx! That was it.